# Regex For Redirect

Tags: regex

I have the source URL say : /abc/def or /abc/def/

I just want to redirect these to pages to another page say. /abd/def/ghi.

What will be the regex for `/abc/def or /abc/def/`

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need a `regex` for that. Anyway, bring more context. How do you use this? Do you need to create a redirect rule in `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0):

```
/(\/\w+\/\w+)\/?/$1\/ghi/

That means:
\/: A / Sign (invalidated by \)
\w+: At least one word sign (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _)
\/: A / Sign (invalidated by \)
\w+: At least one word sign (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _)
\/?: One or none /
$1: The Group (...) from the first part => /abc/def
\/ghi: Add /ghi to the group

(\/\w+\/\w+)\/? : What you are looking for
$1\/ghi : The replacement. $1 is what you found with (\/\w+\/\w+)
```

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)